# Three.js Example code, from StackOverflow, not working

Tags: three.js

I copied and pasted the Three.js code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/three.js/info) into an HTML file and downloaded the `three.js` package from the website, and configured the `<script>` tag to point to the location of the file `three.min.js`.

Nonetheless, when I open the HTML file, it displays a blank white screen.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I tryed the exact same thing and I'm seeing the wireframe cube rotating on screen. A few things to try.

1) drop the three.min.js right in the root folder and copy/paste the example code again without any alterations.

2) did you get the three.min.js from the zip package under the build directory? Or did you navigate the git repo and copy/paste it? If copy/paste was used be sure to click the ["Raw"](https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js) button to get the code without the wrapper HTML.

3) try the latest Firefox or Chrome browsers first. If it works there but not in say Safari, there are a few steps you need to take to enable WebGL in Safari first.

4) your video card may be [blacklisted](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists) due to driver incompatibilities.

If none of these help, then post up the code, where you got the Three.js package, what browser and video card your using and I'll see what else I can do to help :)

Comment: Your suggestion worked; I copied `three.min.js` to the root folder and it worked. Perhaps something was wrong with the script tag (even though I'm sure I typed everything correctly)

Comment: Indeed, perhaps the path to `three.min.js` was a level below the root HTML folder causing some sandboxing issue? Glad its working now.

Comment: Just have finished fixing a little error.))) 

My problem was, that I've written "new Three.WebGLRenderer();" instead of "new THREE.WebGLRenderer();", despite that example code was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Windows hides the file extensions by default. I change it in folder options and it worked.